# How do I get the current count of a metric from Graphite

Tags: graphite, statsd

I am trying to get the value of a metric 'activelogins' from Graphite. I increment the value by 1 every time a user logs in and decrements it when he logs out. I need to show the current number of 'activelogins' in my dashboard.
Querying using
`summarize(stats_counts.user.activelogins,"99years", "sum")`
as expected just gives me the sum and not the current which I actually want.

How do I get the current count of 'activelogins' from Graphite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you could use the absolute of the derivative of `stats_counts.user.activelogins` and than summarize this, as in `absolute(derivative(stats_counts.user.activelogins))`.

Comment: I tried the solution and it is working. The only problem is that it is providing me many data points. Is there any way I can get just the last data point ?

Comment: So you want to fill a whole graph with a single (the last) value or do you want to retrieve that latest value programatically?

Comment: I just want to retrieve the latest value of that particular metric

Comment: Then you should probably investigate the options of the Graphite metrics API that returns the data in JSON and therefore allows you to e.g. extract the latest value - the frontend is specialised for graphs.